# Javascript: While the variable is declared in global scope, it remains undefined inside the function

Tags: javascript

While I define the `starttime` variable without the `var` keyword thus making it global, logging the `starttime` in console gives `undefined`.

```
 starttime = new Date();

setInterval(function(starttime){
    getTimeElapsed(starttime);
}, 1000);
```

How can I access the `starttime` variable inside the function?

Comment: Not overriding it in the function arguments would be a start, I guess.

Comment: The definition in the function signature means when the timeout calls the function, it will set `starttime` to undefined in that scope. Remove the variable name from the function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two variables called `starttime`.

One global, implicitly declared here:

> ```
> starttime = new Date();
> ```

and one local, declared here:

> ```
> function(starttime){
> ```

Since you don't use the local version, the best approach is to **remove that declaration**.

```
setInterval(function(){
```

---

Alternatively, access the global explicitly:

```
getTimeElapsed(window.starttime);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
starttime = new Date();

setInterval(function(){
    getTimeElapsed(starttime);
}, 1000);
```

Now you access the global declared variable `starttime`. While in your code, you were accessing an undefined variable. Why? You function had one argument that you never passed to it. So it's value was undefined.